# preg_replace specific word followed by random number

Tags: php, joomla, tags, preg-replace, joomla-k2

I'd like to replace a specific word followed by random number followed by specific symbol. I figured the correct php function would be `preg_replace` but I have no idea how to proceed.

what I have is a string that contains a joomla non-sef url which looks like that:

```
index.php?option=com_k2&Itemid=378&lang=el&tag=some-tag-name&task=tag&view=itemlist
```

and I need to remove the `Itemid=378&` part. The number 378 could be a different number at any time so I need to catch all numbers.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_replace('/^(.*)Itemid=\d+&?(.*)$/', '$1$2', 'index.php?option=com_k2&Itemid=378&lang=el&tag=some-tag-name&task=tag&view=itemlist');
```

Comment: I think that works, I just have to figure out the best place to put it. stupid joomla, so many php files. Thank you very much

Comment: Based on the above comment, it appears that you either plan on hacking a core file, or don't know how to implement this. As with any system like Joomla, there is a right way and wrong way to do this. Please do yourself a huge favor and learn how to do this properly. In this case, you could create a very simple plugin or use an existing one like http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/rereplacer

Answer (score 2):

```
$new_url_string = preg_replace('/Itemid=\d+&/', '', $the_url_string);
```

Comment: you are not allowed dashes in variable names